# ширина блока-потомка в блоке-родителе

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, позиционирование

нужно чтоб блок-потомок был по ширине окна, и при этом не "ездил" при его уменшении(окна) . Блок-родитель же меньше , нежели ширина окна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот, нужно чтоб желтый блок, принадлежащий красному, был по-ширине окна

Comment: А как пытались? Приложите код примера

Comment: как он может "ездить"?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, так не очень понятно

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(80px - 50vw);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```